# get last inserted(latest added) contract id with same foreign key value of a supplier

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a table called c_supplier_contract
what I want to do is, getting the last inserted **rows** of the each supplier foreign key value having the same value.

below shows the whole table with the image of what I want **with the color of blue** for example.
[image]

---

this is what I want to get...for demonstration I only provided two rows, but table can have many rows like this...

[image]

how to **write mysql query** to get this kind of result? help from anyone greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. (Obviously,) This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: What does "the last inserted row" mean?--exactly. (Why does your example have the rows it has?) Is LAST_INSERT_ID relevant?

Comment: @philipxy, my scenario is, I have a supplier and each supplier has many supplier agreements. for example supplier id with 27 , which I means get the last inserted row is , getting latest supplier contract id, for example in here it is 16.

Comment: Please clarify posts via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy I edited my question. anyway I got the answer. but thank you for the dropping by for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is 'the last insert time', so i select last `supp_date_expired` 
And db-fiddle link is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xikqEdLnXwU732uXjuFt31/1)
 
I hope it helps.

```
select supp_cont_id,
       supp_cont_desc,
       supp_date_signed,
       supp_date_expired,
       supp_fk_id
  from temptable
 where (supp_fk_id, supp_date_expired) in (select supp_fk_id, max(supp_date_expired)
                                             from temptable
                                            where ifnull(supp_fk_id, 0) != 0
                                            group by supp_fk_id
                                           having count(1) > 1);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.I got it modified to suit my question.